# #include <string> adding ~43 KB to my exe

Tags: c++, native, codeblocks

I'm using Code::Blocks to write my program and when I include `<string>` (or `<iostream>`) the size of my exe grows. My program is very simple and I need to keep it small <20kb. I'm pretty sure this is happening because of the C++ Standards Committee swapped the old .h versions for many new libraries without the .h. But how would I keep it from adding the ~43kb? Are there settings for Code::Blocks so that it wont add the extra kb or is there another native lib I can use?

Comment: Why do you need to keep it below 20kB?

Comment: No, it's because <string> is a class which requires runtime support. when you include that header than the compiler needs to include std::basic_string and friends into your module.

Comment: If you completely avoid C++ stuff and only go with C, it'll reduce your program's size somewhat while almost certainly increasing the complexity.  Handling such complexity might in fact require more space than the resulting C++ code would.  It's difficult to get away with <20KB sometimes these days...especially on Windows.  For example, a simple bit of `#include <stdio.h> int main (void) { return !puts ("Hello World!"); }` with MinGW (GCC on Windows) yields 8K alone and that's using native libraries.  If I use the MinGW libraries (`-ansi`), it becomes >20K already.

Comment: Using the `/MD` flag with Visual C++ 2008 Express to use the MSVCRT library rather than the LIBCMT library and then stripping it using `strip.exe` from MinGW yields 5K...and that's the smallest that I can get it.  My point is that 20K is a bit unrealistic these days for Windows.  I should also mention that you can use a utility called UPX to make it smaller, but that's at the expense of memory cost.  Less cost to you in EXE size = more cost in memory.  There's a trade-off somewhere that is unavoidable.  Sorry.  = /

Comment: You *need* to stay below 20kb? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: @Dustin: You can actually get it down to something in the hundreds of bytes, but then you're starting to strip away compatibility layers.

Comment: @Longpoke: Exactly, and that could very well be a bad idea.  I suppose it depends on how compatible the code should be...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If size is your #1 concern (and if you have to keep things < 20KB, then it probably is) then the standard C++ library is probably not the way to go. In fact, *any* C++ at all (RTTI, exceptions, etc) is probably a bad idea and you would be better off just sticking with straight C.

Comment: I'd agree with you on the point of libraries, the C++ language itself isn't entirely expensive. For instance if you only stick to basic classes where you'd use structs, and use virtual inheritance only where you'd use a function pointer, it should be fine.

Comment: @Longpoke: Virtual inheritance should only be used in a few special cases where Multiple Inheritance is involved, where you inherit from two classes which share a common base class, and you only want one copy of the base class in that derived class. It has nothing to do with function pointers. If you mean virtual *functions*, however, that's a different story...

Comment: If I used C, would I still have access to windows.h, wininet.h just as I do now or would I have to use different stuff?

Comment: @Lineau: Windows.h and Wininet.h are C libraries.

Comment: Yes, the Windows API is pure C anyway, so you still have access to all of that.

Comment: I only started teaching myself C++ about a month and a half ago (I have experience with C# and PHP) and I don't know C. Now that I have to use all of the C functions I might as well just program in C. Thanks pointing that out.

Comment: @Billy ONeal, yeah I meant virtual functions, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

Neither `<string>` nor `<iostream>` are renamed/modified C headers.  They are both new to C++.  If you want to stick to C libraries, you can use `<cstring>` and `<cstdio>` (among others), which are the C++ versions of the C headers `"string.h"` and `"stdio.h"`.

Comment: This is really what I'm looking for. While just strait C is really the best solution, this is what I have to do to fix my immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

The header versions without .h aren't different from the others. The .h versions are mostly provided for compability. The additional size would be the `string` class, and the size isn't too surprising. If you wan't zero size overhead: Don't use std::string, but `char*`.

The next step would be compiler options. Most compilers have the possibility to disable RTTI and to optimize for size. `-Os -fno-rtti` would be the right switches for gcc.

Otherwise all standard tricks for size optimization apply:

- Don't have any static data, always calculate
- Don't use virtual functions
- Pack things tight, use bitfields
- Maybe C is a better pick than C++ (This is subject to debate.)

Comment: That only knocked out .5kb :/

Comment: You mean virtual *functions*, not virtual inheritance. Virtual inheritance does not significantly affect code size.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using compiler switches to optimize based on file size.  If you don't get anywhere you could try using [stlport](http://stlport.sourceforge.net/) but I'm not sure if the results will be any better.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to build your app on - release mode instead of -debug one. That will reduce your app size a lot.

Comment: -1 for being too lazy to type out the **word** "your" and for not using the shift key.

Comment: @advs889: +1 to your comment for being able to type a standard English sentence. Also, you aren't a C++ programmer if you aren't pedantic ;)

Comment: @Billy ONeal:
+1 for the typo in advs89's nick. Goes well with your comment about pedantry :).

Comment: @Slacker: Doh! (asdfasdfasdf 15 chars)